# document.getElementById returns null after create new packery using angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

so I have this html markup

```
<button ng-click="create()">create  list</button>
```

I made it so whenever I click it I create a new list using packery jQuery plugin

```
app.directive('packery', ['$compile', function($compile) {
   return {
    scope:false,
    restrict: "EA",
    link: function(scope,elm, attr) {
        $.bridget('packery', Packery); //convert Packery object into jquery plugin

        var $container = $(elm).packery(); //install packery plugin

        var item = {
          create: function() {
              var elem = document.createElement("div");
              var panelHeight = document.createAttribute("panel-height");
              panelHeight.value = "";
              elem.setAttributeNode(panelHeight);
              elem.className = "item";

              var treeGrid = document.createElement("grid-test");
              treeGrid.id = "grids";
              treeGrid.className = "little-font";
              elem.appendChild(treeGrid);

              return $compile(elem)(scope);
          }


     scope.create = function() {
         var $items = $(item.create());

         $container.append($items).packery('appended', $items);
         $container.packery();
         $items.each(draggable);

         console.log(document.getElementById("grids")); //here it return with the object
       }
     }
   }
  }
]});
```

obviously I create a custom directive which is "grid-test" isn't it ? but the weird thing is when I'm using document.getElementById is always returning null whereas what I want is returning the "grids" element as I mentioned above on treeGrid variable

```
app.directive('gridTest', [ function() {
    return {
      scope:false,
      restrict: "EA",
      link: function(scope,elm, attr) {

           var container = document.getElementById("grids");
           var treegrid = new links.TreeGrid(container, []); //I need the container to install this new object but it always returns a null :(
      }
    } 
}]);
```

I really stuck, could you guys help me ?

==================================================================================

it seems that I couldn't save my plunkr so I guess I will copy paste the codes in here

index.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html ng-app="myApp">

  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <title></title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
    <script data-require="jquery" data-semver="1.9.1" src="//cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script data-require="angular.js@1.0.7" data-semver="1.0.7" src="https://code.angularjs.org/1.0.7/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="script.js"></script>
  </head>

  <body ng-controller="test">
     {{title}}
     <hr>
     <create-button></create-button>
     <hr>
     <div id="container">
       <new-directive id="new"></new-directive>
     </div>
  </body>

</html>
```

script.js

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.title = "Creating custom directive";
});

app.directive('createButton', function($compile) {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: false,
    template: "<button>Create</button>",
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {

      var item = {
        create: function() {

          var treeGrid = document.createElement("new-directive");
          treeGrid.id = "grids";

          return $compile(treeGrid)(scope);
        }
      }

      angular.element(elm).click(function() {
        var $container = $('#container');
        var $items = $(item.create());

        $container.append($items);
      });
    }
  }
});

app.directive('newDirective', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "EA",
    scope: false,
    template: "this is new custom directive",
    link: function(scope, elm, attr) {
      var container = document.getElementById(attr.id);
      console.log(container);
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: You already have that element, it's the `elm` parameter passed in the link function. `attr.id` will lead you to that same element.

Comment: I don't understand, would you care to explain more ? @MarcelGwerder

Comment: `attr` will contain all attributes of the element of the directive, which is `elm`. So no need to get the element again using the id, you already have it, it's `elm`.

Comment: well actually I need it to install it again on gridTest so I really need the document.getElementById('grids') working on 'gridTest' directives, I've made some changes on the codes, please take a look if you don't mind @MarcelGwerder

Comment: You still try to get the same element. You assign the `grids` id to your `grid-test` element. If you wan't `$container` you'll need to use his id...

Comment: I'm sorry, could you provide me with the example codes based on my question codes above ? @MarcelGwerder

Comment: If you can setup a working/non-working example on [plunker](http://plnkr.co/) I can.

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/ZLdHkmr1zb1izNMfE278 please have a look @MarcelGwerder

Comment: @MarcelGwerder it seems that I couldn't save my plunkr work so I just copy paste the codes in the question you could see it above.. please help me

Answer (score 1):

I was not sure if I really could get your code working because the approach is pretty "special".
So I started more or less from scratch to create a `packery` and a `packery-item` directive (**Inline demo at the bottom and also a [plunker demo](http://plnkr.co/edit/jWPn6F3WVvQ57F6EP6um?p=preview)**).

```
<packery>
    <div class="packery-item" ng-repeat="item in items" >
        <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>

        {{item.text}}
    </div>
</packery>
```

The `packery` directive is pretty much just a wrapper that provides the container element for the `packery-item` directive.

```
app.directive('packery', function() {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: false,
        transclude: true,
        template: '<div ng-transclude class="js-packery"></div>',
        controller: function($scope, $element) {
            this.container = angular.element($element.children()[0]);
            this.packeryConfig = {
                gutter: 10
            };

            this.container.packery(this.packeryConfig);
        }
    }
});
```

The `packery-item` directives adds an item to the packery container and removes it when it is destroyed:

```
app.directive('packeryItem', function() {
    return {
        restrict: "C",
        scope: false,
        require: '^packery',
        link: function(scope, elem, attr, packeryCtrl) {
            packeryCtrl.container.packery('addItems', elem);
            packeryCtrl.container.packery(packeryCtrl.packeryConfig);

            scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
                packeryCtrl.container.packery(packeryCtrl.packeryConfig);
            });
        }
    }
});
```

I hope this is as close to your end goal as it gets.
Have a look at the complete snippet with a working demo bellow.

```js
var app = angular.module('myApp', []);

app.controller('test', function($scope) {
  $scope.items = [];

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    $scope.items.push({
      title: 'Item',
      text: 'Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet'
    });
  }

  $scope.removeItem = function(item) {
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
  }
});


app.directive('packery', function() {
  return {
    restrict: 'E',
    scope: false,
    transclude: true,
    template: '<div ng-transclude class="js-packery"></div>',
    controller: function($scope, $element) {
      this.container = angular.element($element.children()[0]);
      this.packeryConfig = {
        gutter: 10
      };

      this.container.packery(this.packeryConfig);
    }
  }
});


app.directive('packeryItem', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    scope: false,
    require: '^packery',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, packeryCtrl) {
      packeryCtrl.container.packery('addItems', elem);
      packeryCtrl.container.packery(packeryCtrl.packeryConfig);

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
        packeryCtrl.container.packery(packeryCtrl.packeryConfig);
      });
    }
  }
});
```

```css
.packery-item {
  width: 25%;
  border: solid 1px #000;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
.packery-item.w2 {
  width: 50%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.22/angular.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/packery/1.3.0/packery.pkgd.min.js"></script>

<div ng-app="myApp">
  <div ng-controller="test">
    <button ng-click="addItem()">Add new item</button>
    <hr>

    <packery>
      <div class="packery-item" ng-repeat="item in items">
        <h3>{{item.title}}</h3>
        <button ng-click="removeItem(item)">Remove</button>
        <p>
          {{item.text}}
        </p>
      </div>
    </packery>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: could you copy paste the scripts from plunkr into your answer section and also the name of the file just like I did ? it always return with "import plunkr not found" I guess plunkr server is error right now

Comment: nevermind, turns out my isp is blocking the plunkr website, I'm really sorry and thank you so much for your response!

Comment: I added an inline snippet and running example... have a look at the bottom of my post.

Comment: I tried it, and actually adding the packery component and destroying one of the packery object is already done also on my side, the goals that I want to go is create another custom directive inside the packery component using this library http://almende.github.io/chap-links-library/js/treegrid/doc/index.html that's why I insist on want to make the getElementById working, so could you help me? if not then it's okay because your response is really good and helped me, thanks a lot I appreaciate it! :) and yes, in the future I will make it using ng-repeat!