# drag and drop using packery and jqueryui didn't behave properly on angularjs

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

this is a follow up question from this question

> **[document.getElementById returns null after create new packery using angularjs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27676288/document-getelementbyid-returns-null-after-create-new-packery-using-angularjs)**

so basically I adding some of the functionality to drag and drop on packery jquery plugin using [**jqueryui Draggable**](http://jqueryui.com/draggable/), and also I include the functionality to add, dragging, and deleting an item inside the packery element

this is the adding functionality

```
app.controller('test', function($scope) {

  $scope.addItem = function() { //this is the adding new list functionality
    $scope.items.push({
      title: 'Item',
      text: 'Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet'
    });
  }

});
```

this is the drag and drop functionality

```
app.directive('packeryItem', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    scope: false,
    require: '^packery',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, packeryCtrl) {

      elem.draggable({
        containment:"parent",
        stack:".packery-item"
      });

      packeryCtrl.container.packery('bindUIDraggableEvents', elem);

    }
  }
});
```

for now all is okay, the functionality works fine the animation and transition all fine, the problem occurred when I implement the delete list functionality..

this is the delete list functionality

```
app.controller('test', function($scope) {

  $scope.removeItem = function(item) { //delete list functinoality by using splice function 
    $scope.items.splice($scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
  }

});
```

from the splice list functionality, it broadcasted $destroy function so I use it to relayout the packery plugin

```
app.directive('packeryItem', function() {
  return {
    restrict: "C",
    scope: false,
    require: '^packery',
    link: function(scope, elem, attr, packeryCtrl) {

      scope.$on('$destroy', function() { //this is the relayouting functionality
        packeryCtrl.container.packery(packeryCtrl.packeryConfig);
      });

    }
  }
});
```

the interesting part is, now the dragging and dropping didn't work properly, everytime I drag the item and hovered another item, it didn't relayouting the way it supposed to be. it just overlaying another item in the list, I don't know why...

anyone care to elaborate ? this is the working [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0W43ddBryR6m8XSHTiMP?p=preview)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've created a workaround to solved this issue using my own logic, by deleting the DOM first using packery functionality, then splice the array from `$scope.items`

this is the remove functionality

```
scope.remove = function(item) {
                        packeryCtrl.container.packery('remove', elm);
                        scope.items.splice(scope.items.indexOf(item), 1);
                    }
```

this is the working [**plunkr**](http://plnkr.co/edit/0W43ddBryR6m8XSHTiMP?p=preview)